# RxJS Observable returns data immediately, why?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, typescript, rxjs

In my current project I've found the function given below:

```
translateString(stringToTranslate: string) {
    let translation;
    this.translateService.get(stringToTranslate).subscribe(
        data => {
            translation = data;
        });
    return translation;
}
```

It looks ridiculous since [TranslateService.get()](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/src/translate.service.ts#L368) method returns an Observable in every case, but it actually works somehow (the translated string is returned immediately)... What is the explanation of this behavior? Shouldn't callback function be added to the execution stack and run later?

Comment: it just looks like your value is returned to subscribe before `translation` variable is returned. It would be unreliable though, you are likely to get `undefined` translation.Observable will return value to subscriber when it gets it.

Comment: @suraj, the question is why? I think it's something about `Observable.of(string)`

Comment: Looking at the code I suppose it _could_ be going to the final else which is just an Observable of a value and will return without delay.But as I mentioned it is unreliable..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact you're using Observables doesn't automatically mean that everything is going to be called in a separate JavaScript callback.

In fact most of the default Observables and operators emit everything immediately and don't use any Scheduler by default. For example have a look at this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ArrayObservable.ts#L118

This is obviously different when using for example the `delay()` operator which needs to schedule execution, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/delay.ts#L52.

For example consider the following example:

```
Observable.from([1,2,3], Scheduler.async)
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));

Observable.from(['a','b','c'], Scheduler.async)
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Which schedules each emission into another JS callback:

```
1
"a"
2
"b"
3
"c"
```

See demo: https://jsbin.com/zalugev/3/edit?js,console

If you don't set any scheduler everything will be emitted immediately (synchronously):

```
Observable.from([1,2,3])
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));

Observable.from(['a','b','c'])
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Which prints the following:

```
1
2
3
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

See demo: https://jsbin.com/zalugev/4/edit?js,console

Regarding your question, you shouldn't rely on the 3rd party library to emit values immediately because you never know when this changes and your code will break.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it explains the behavior pretty well. I agree and am going to refactor that code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that could be the issue here, but some observables emit synchronously. This is the case of `Observable.of` for example I believe. If `translateService` is synchronous, you would then immediately get your subscription observer called and your `translation` value filled.

You can influence the timing of the emission by using schedulers, which is probably the less documented part of rxjs. Have a look at [`https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md), section `Schedulers Renamed`

Comment: I think it's a kind of issue as it allows to write code like in the question. That's unexpected behavior for me.

Comment: Observables do not have asynchrony as part of their contracts. They modelize a sequence of values with a push interface (instead of the usual pull). The code that you wrote is not very robust anyways. How would you know when your translation is done? What you should do is `translateString(stringToTranslate: string) { return this.translateService.get(stringToTranslate) }` and then get your translation by adding a `map` operator somewhere, and then some `translateObs | async` some other place if that goes into a model\

Answer (score 1):

An Observable is essentially just a wrapper for `onSuccess()`, `onError()` and `onComplete()` callbacks. If functions that are executed are synchronous an Observable will be too. This is core functionality of an Observable (the rest is just cleanup):

```
export class Observable {
  constructor(subscribe) {}
  subscribe(observerOrNext, error, complete) {} // callbacks
}
Observable.create = (subscribe) => {
    return new Observable(subscribe); // dot-chaining
}
```

Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/uQ1zhJHclvs) where André Staltz constructs observable from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Your `translateString` function returns immediately because of your `return translation` line fires before the observable completes.  Observables are async and thus your `this.translateService.get(stringToTranslate)` hasn't completed before the `return` statement.

I would remove the return statement and just let the data value get assigned to `translation` when the observable completes.  If you are trying to chain functions together, I would look at `flatMap` to call another function on the response of `this.translateService.get(stringToTranslate)`.

The `subscribe` behaves in a way like a callback in that it executes the observable and gives the response in a success/error/completed fashion.

```
....subscribe(
    data => //success data,
    error => //error data,
    completed => //observable completed
);
```

Comment: Actually OP is saying he is getting the translated value immediately.Observable is completing before translation is returned